# Chrome Extension: How to get Element from active Tab Page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a chrome-extension. There is a button on my popup.html which clicks on an element in the active tab. 
In theory I think I understand how to do that but right now I'm stuck here:

---

HTML on the Site:

```
<td class="confirmButtons">
<form action="modcp.php" method="post">
<input class="formAction" type="hidden" name="" value="">
<ul>
<li class="button"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="formAction" rel="confirm" tabindex="2"><strong>Ja</strong></a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="buttonGroup">
<li class="first"></li>
<li class="button"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="formAction" rel="cancel" tabindex="2"><strong>Nein</strong></a></li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="formAction" rel="cancel" tabindex="2">
<li class="last"></li>
</a></ul></form></td>
```

The Code I use in my content_script.js:

```
function clickJa() {
    console.log("clickJA");
    var confirmButton = document.getElementsByClassName("confirmButtons"); 
    console.log(confirmButton);        
}
```

---

Now, my Problem:
When I paste the Code in the Console it returns an Array with 1 element - thats fine.
When I press my button in the extension ut returns an Array with 0 elements - thats not good and I have no Idea whats wrong... do you have some Ideas?

Greetings and thanks for every Idea & answer
Lime

Comment: It means the site doesn't have a button yet at the time you run the content script. Depending on the goal and how you inject there are several solutions like timers, MutationObserver, events.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: What wOxxOm said is the most likely problem. However, we can't be sure without enough code to duplicate the problem (and the website's URL so we know where to test).

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, we need more details. However, let's try to understand:

- You have a button in your popup page
- When you click on this button in your button page, you want an element to be clicked on in the active page.

From where do you call the function:

```
clickJa()
```

From the popup page?

If it is from the popup page, then the function is executed inside the popup page, and therefore, you will not have your element. (As it is not in the popup page but on the active tab)

If your goal is only to click on an element from the popup page, then maybe the simplest thing to do is something like:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript( {
    code: "document.getElementsByClassName(\"confirmButtons\").click();"
}, function() {
      console.log("Element clicked !");
});
```

(Not tested though)

More info about script execution:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript